# Using sort and size commands edit code to get desired sizes in excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, sorting

Using python: Modify the "Sort Timer" program to collect the data to complete the spreadsheet. Adjust the "size" variable in the program to the sizes indicated in the spreadsheet. Replace the Selection sort method in the program with the code for the other sort methods as needed.Round all times to the nearest second:

```
import random
import time
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)

def main():

    size = 300000
    list = []

    for i in range(size):
        list.append(random.randint(0, 100000 - 1))

    print("Starting Sort ...")
    startTime = time.time()
    quickSort(list)
    endTime = time.time()
    print("Exection time for Selection Sort with", size, "values is: ",
    endTime - startTime)

# The function for sorting the numbers
def quickSort(list):
    quickSortHelper(list, 0, len(list) - 1)

def quickSortHelper(list, first, last):
    if last > first:
        pivotIndex = partition(list, first, last)
        quickSortHelper(list, first, pivotIndex - 1)
        quickSortHelper(list, pivotIndex + 1, last)

# Partition list[first..last]
def partition(list, first, last):
    pivot = list[first]  # Choose the first element as the pivot
    low = first + 1  # Index for forward search
    high = last  # Index for backward search

    while high > low:
        # Search forward from left
        while low <= high and list[low] <= pivot:
            low += 1

        # Search backward from right
        while low <= high and list[high] > pivot:
            high -= 1

        # Swap two elements in the list
        if high > low:
            list[high], list[low] = list[low], list[high]

    while high > first and list[high] >= pivot:
        high -= 1

    # Swap pivot with list[high]
    if pivot > list[high]:
        list[first] = list[high]
        list[high] = pivot
        return high
    else:
        return first

main()
```

The Excel spreadsheet named Sort Compare.xlsx looks as follows:

[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It is hard to read.

Comment: Sorry about that!

Comment: So what is the problem?  "sorting issue" isn't helpful.  I'll you've done is quote your homework problem.

Comment: I'm not sure where to go from here! I'm a beginner when it comes to programming.

Comment: Please read the [ask] and [mcve] guidelines and update the question.

Comment: Not looking for anyone to do the work for me, just looking for guidance...